Solutions to differential equation $-\frac{d^2u}{dr^2} = \lambda e^u $
I'm trying to check that the following functions
\begin{equation} 
  u_\lambda(r)=\ln \frac{8 b_{-}}{\left(1+\lambda b_{-} r^2\right)^2}, \quad U_\lambda(r)=\ln \frac{8 b_{+}}{\left(1+\lambda b_{+} r^2\right)^2}
 \end{equation}
where $b_{ \pm}=\frac{4-\lambda \pm \sqrt{16-8 \lambda}}{\lambda^2}, r \in[0,1]$ are  solutions the this differential equations with boundary conditions where the variable is r and B is a ball of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
This come from the Dupainge Book Stable solutions of elliptic partial differential equations page 34 . Here my attempt.
The differential equation is
\begin{equation*}
-\frac{d^2u}{dr^2} = \lambda e^u \quad \text{en B}
\end{equation*}
and the boundary condition
\begin{equation*}
  u=0 \quad \text{en}\; \partial B
 \end{equation*}
Since the procedure is similar for both, we will only develop one of them. We have the function
\begin{equation*}
 u_\lambda(r) = \ln \frac{8 b_{-}}{\left(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2\right)^2} 
\end{equation*}
we use properties of logarithms
\begin{equation*}
u_\lambda(r) = \ln 8 b_{-} - 2 \ln \left(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2\right)
\end{equation*}
the first derivative is
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{du_\lambda}{dr} = -2 \cdot \frac{2 \lambda b_{-} r}{1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2} = -\frac{4 \lambda b_{-} r}{1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2} 
 \end{equation*}
we calculate its second derivative.
\begin{equation*}
[ \frac{d^2u_\lambda}{dr^2} = -\frac{d}{dr} \left( \frac{4 \lambda b_{-} r}{1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2} \right)
 \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{d^2u_\lambda}{dr^2} = -4 \lambda b_{-} \left( \frac{(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2) - \lambda b_{-} r \cdot 2r}{(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2)^2} \right) = -4 \lambda b_{-} \left( \frac{1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2 - 2 \lambda b_{-} r^2}{(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2)^2} \right) 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
[ \frac{d^2u_\lambda}{dr^2} = -4 \lambda b_{-} \left( \frac{1 - \lambda b_{-} r^2}{(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2)^2} \right)
\end{equation*}
we introduce all the expressions into the equation and verify that we obtain the same expression on both sides of the equation.
\begin{equation*}
 -\frac{d^2u_\lambda}{dr^2} = \lambda e^{u_\lambda} 
\end{equation*}
we calculate $e^{u_\lambda} $:
\begin{equation*}
 e^{u_\lambda} = \frac{8 b_{-}}{\left(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2\right)^2} 
\end{equation*}
Substituting into the equation
\begin{equation*}
 -\left( -4 \lambda b_{-} \frac{1 - \lambda b_{-} r^2}{(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2)^2} \right) = 4 \lambda b_{-} \frac{1 - \lambda b_{-} r^2}{(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2)^2} 
\end{equation*}
This is equal to
\begin{equation*}
 4 \lambda b_{-} \frac{1 - \lambda b_{-} r^2}{(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2)^2} 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 \lambda e^{u_\lambda} = \lambda \frac{8 b_{-}}{\left(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2\right)^2} = 8 \lambda b_{-} \frac{1}{\left(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2\right)^2} 
\end{equation*}
but left and right side don't coincide
\begin{equation*}
 4 \lambda b_{-} \frac{1 - \lambda b_{-} r^2}{(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2)^2} = \lambda \frac{8 b_{-}}{\left(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2\right)^2}
\end{equation*}

According to proposition 2.3.1 of the book, those functions are solutions to the equation $-\Delta u=\lambda e^u$. In 2D, the radial part of $\Delta u$ is $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right).$

Yes it is true that you are saying ,but $u_{\lambda}(r)$ and $U_{\lambda}(r)$ should be also solutions to the problem.

What the author claims is that those functions are solutions to $−\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{du}{dr}\right)=λe^u.$ Have you checked this claim?

Ok, I tried again, the error is what you had written before. I forgot to put it in polar form. I rewrite the comment with the correct solution.

Here the correct answer
\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{du}{dr}\right)=\lambda e^u
\end{equation}
The left-hand side of the differential equation is:
\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} \left( r \frac{du_\lambda}{dr} \right) = -\frac{1}{r} \left( -4 \lambda b_{-} \cdot \frac{2r}{(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2)^2} \right)
= \frac{8 \lambda b_{-}}{(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2)^2}
\end{equation}
right-hand side is
\begin{equation}
e^{u_\lambda(r)} = \frac{8 b_{-}}{(1 + \lambda b_{-} r^2)^2}
\end{equation}
so we have the same expression
